# algorithm for code jQuery hide & show

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have a question about jQuery hide & show:

```html
<select class='class1'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type='text' value='2' class='class2'>
<input type='text' value='2' class='class2'>
<input type='text' value='4' class='class2'>
```

My Algorithm :

1. If I select value 2 and then every class2 have value 2 $.show 
   else $.hide 
   or if(class1 == class2) $.show else $.hide
2. If I Select value 1 and then every class2 $.show because value 1 nothing in value class2

how to write code for this algorithm:
I have try like this

```
$.('.class2').each(){
if(class1==class2){
  class2.show;
}else{
  class2.hide;
}
```

thanks

Comment: what js have you got so far?

Comment: Plz try something yourself first then post your code if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: hi, flauntster i try like this                                                                           $.('.class2').each(){if(class1==class2){class2.show}else{class2.hide}                                                                      but not like my algoritma,

Comment: hy sgt Bose, I want just $show if same value, otherwise it will be hidden

Comment: Your question doesn't conveys your need. Even your expected output is not understandable you need to elaborate it precisely.

Comment: hi, Uchiha I want just $show if same value, otherwise it will be hidden

Comment: You can try something like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/YNnCw/262/

Comment: hi kurenai kunai yah such as like that but a little difference please see : https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/5aRvF/298/

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
$('.select_class').on('change',function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.show_class').hide();
  $('.show_class[value="' + value +'"]').show();
})
```

And next time, please, read properly [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) where everything was written very well

---

**UPDATE**

```
$('.select_class').on('change',function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.show_class').show();
  if(  $('.show_class[value="' + value +'"]').length > 0 )
    $('.show_class[value!="' + value +'"]').hide();
})
```

Comment: hy xAqweRx,  thanks for your answer but not like that  please see: https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/5aRvF/298/